# How call event onTouchEvent in process event OnItemLongClick of ListView?

Tags: android

I move Item by event onTouch

But i only want move Item when LongClick and move.

How call event onTouchEvent in process event OnItemLongClick of ListView?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Imports
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector;


//Constructor
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), gestureListener);


//Listener
private final OnGestureListener gestureListener = new OnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        //DO YOUR STUFF IN HERE
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
};

//Touch
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean result = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener;?

Comment: I touch on my listview. Code in LongPress still work.